# How to control the space between two labels during run time

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Im using Visual Studio 2015 Community C#.
I have two labels on a Windows form suppose Label1 and Label2.
These labels will get filled up with user input namely first name and last name.
How to put even space between them so that during runtime the first name doesn't over lap the last name.

```
                     AbrahLincoln                  Abraham Lincoln
                 (Label1^)(^Label2)              (^Label1) (^Label2)
```

For example: how to make this ^ INTO  that >>>>>>>>>>>>^^

Because if I put space in the Form Design before runtime then for other names It will come like this:       John(unnecessary space)Doe

Hope you have understood my problem.
Thanks for your time. :D

Answer (score 1):

Controls are located in a form based on coordinates. Luckily for you these controls have properties that tell you the coordinate for the top, left, right, bottom of a control. So  you could dynamically move the right label after setting the text.

```
Label2.Point = new Point(Label1.Right + 5, Y-coord);
```

An easier way would be to play about with the labels properties in the designer.

Comment: Thanks! For your help but could you be more specific with which label properties? @horHAY

Comment: You could change the autosize property to false, and make the label a fixed size. Then for the left hand label, set RightToLeft to yes. That was it will always be next to the other label.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to `anchor` `label1` to the right and `label2` to the left. That way you should have a clean middle line, and as the text grows larger it pushes outwards on does not overlap inwards over each other.

However you need an object to anchor to and luckily the `SplitContainer` works excellent for this.

[image]

Also consider setting the autosize property to off and maxing the widths of the labels. Large enough for the string you expect.

Comment: This should work. Or stop the labels from auto-sizing, make them as wide as the widest expected string, and set the left one's text to right-justified and the right one's text to left-justified.

Comment: @MatthewWatson how to set the left's one's text to right justified and the right one's text to left-justified?

Comment: @DheerajDevaraj Click on the label, Press F4, under Appearance you should see a TextAlign property.

Comment: It's not for the split container. It's to set the text justify like you asked @DheerajDevaraj

Comment: @MFusiki I have changed no Properties of the SplitContainer. Only property I have changed is of Label1's anchor to right and Label2's anchor to left and changed the left one's text to right-justified and the right one's text to left-justified. This all I should do, yes? I have done so but no avail.

Comment: Have you made them full width?

Comment: Full width, Sorry but I am new to coding so how do I set it to full width. The auto-size property is true.

Comment: You can switch that off, then you should receive resizing handles on your labels.

Comment: But still the problem exists if the name is too big it becomes like this:                    -                              Abhr Lincoln

Comment: Have you made it full width?

Comment: Yes but then it looks like this: Abhraham *unwanted space*           Lincoln Oh wait I got it thank you so much my mistake I was just being an idiot

Comment: Consider marking as answer if it helped you. Glad you could figure it out .

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making it one label?
As in

```
theOnlyLabel.Text = $"{dataObject.FirstName} {dataObject.LastName}";
```

or, if you're using textboxes, something like

```
theOnlyLabel.Text = $"{txtFirstName.Text} {txtLastName.Text}";
```

Otherwise, I'm afraid, you'd have to realign these two labels every time your first or last name changes.